# Как настроить правый клик мыши в linux для работы контекстного меню?

Tags: linux

На многих дистрибутивах linux контекстное меню вызывается при нажатии(не клике) на правую кнопку мыши, возможно ли как то перенастроить данное поведение чтобы событие вызова меню отрабатывало после клика, то есть когда кнопка отпускается.
На windoows именно так реализовано.

Comment: Где именно так настроено? Наверное, у вас какой-то графический интерфейс, который так делает. Какой?

Comment: @Argo Troll - то, что Вы описываете - это обычное поведение XOrg. Да, оно отличается от винды, но в таком поведении есть свои плюсы.

Comment: [никак](https://askubuntu.com/q/10586/416190)

Comment: Ну что уж прям "никак". Это на виндовз никак, а на линуксах исходники к вашим услугам...

Comment: @KoVadim не совсем понимаю какие плюсы можно из этого извлечь.

Comment: к примеру, экономия клика. То есть, нажимаю правую кнопку, но не отпускаю ее. Навожу на нужный пункт меню и отпускаю. Получается один клик вместо двух.

Comment: *На многих дистрибутивах linux* - Дистрибутив тут не причём. Как уже сказал dim0n,  такое поведение определяется **графической оболочкой**.  У Вас что - KDE, Gnome, Xfce... Их много! И в каждой - свой способ настройки.

Answer (score 0):

Использую метод из коментария @aleksandr barakin [никак](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10586/right-click-menu-on-mouse-release-windows-behavior)
Там есть вариант с easystroke, в принципе работает.